# HTTP Error 404.17 Not Found - IIS 10 on Windows Svr 2016

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-10

I am trying to serve up a website with web forms.  This is an older project converted from framework 3.5 to 4.6.1.  The error message I get is:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
>   The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.
>   Most likely causes:
>   The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.

A little digging turned up suggestions to make sure all .NET Framework features were installed.

[image]

In the old days, the catch all was to reregister ASP.Net using aspnet_regiis -i, but that doesn't work on my OS.  So I also tried this command:
`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all`
Result says operation completed successfully, but still doesn't work.

Something I find odd in the ISAPI filters in IIS is there is no entry for ASP.Net 4, only ASP.NET 2.

[image]

What else can I try?

Comment: Expand IIS in Server Manager features and ASP.NET 4 is under it.

Comment: Do you have a scr shot or more explicit instructions, Lex?  In Server Manager, Dashboard, under Features there is no entry for "IIS" or "Web Server".  Under Server Roles, Web Server (IIS), Web Server, Application Development I have ASP.NET 4.6 installed.